# How to link glext.lib to windows 64bit application?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, opengl, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm converting my `32bit` project to `64bit` and have a handful of bugs because of that. Most of them are solvable, but I've got a problem with hooking up `glext.lib` there.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file glext.lib
```

On 32bit version it worked ok.

What should I do?

Here are my definitions and includes for x86 project;

```
#pragma once
#include "gl_camera.h"
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include "utils.h"
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <GL\glext.h>
#include "navigation.h"
#include "Resource.h"


1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glBindBuffer в функции "public: void __cdecl window_glview::add_mesh_to_GPU(class mesh *)" (?add_mesh_to_GPU@window_glview@@QEAAXPEAVmesh@@@Z)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glGenBuffers в функции "public: void __cdecl window_glview::add_mesh_to_GPU(class mesh *)" (?add_mesh_to_GPU@window_glview@@QEAAXPEAVmesh@@@Z)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glBufferData в функции "public: void __cdecl window_glview::add_mesh_to_GPU(class mesh *)" (?add_mesh_to_GPU@window_glview@@QEAAXPEAVmesh@@@Z)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glAttachShader в функции "public: bool __cdecl window_glview::init_scene_shaders(void)" (?init_scene_shaders@window_glview@@QEAA_NXZ)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glCompileShader в функции "public: bool __cdecl window_glview::init_scene_shaders(void)" (?init_scene_shaders@window_glview@@QEAA_NXZ)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glCreateProgram в функции "public: bool __cdecl window_glview::init_scene_shaders(void)" (?init_scene_shaders@window_glview@@QEAA_NXZ)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glCreateShader в функции "public: bool __cdecl window_glview::init_scene_shaders(void)" (?init_scene_shaders@window_glview@@QEAA_NXZ)
1>window_glview.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ glEnableVertexAttribArray в функции "public: void __cdecl window_glview::add_mesh_to_GPU(class mesh *)" (?add_mesh_to_GPU@window_glview@@QEAAXPEAVmesh@@@Z)
```

Comment: You need a 64-bit version of that library. Either download it if a 64-bit build is available, or build it from source.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have your **Library Directories** configured properly for your 64 bit build, and so Visual Studio isn't able to find the link library.

In Visual Studio the library paths used to be configured from *Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories*, but it changed (in VS2010 I think), and they are now configured from *Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories*.

Check what you have set there for your 32 bit build, and then you'll need to add the corresponding path for your 64 bit build.

Comment: Thanks , I've added this glext.lib to a place that the linker actually checks out, but the problem has not solved. I've updated the question to show you how it's acting now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I've found out.
To use basic OpenGL functions in 64bit configuration you still need the same OpenGL32.lib
I've read this page to find this out:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows
Here is what they say:

> ...Under Windows, you need to statically link to a library called
>   OpenGL32.lib (note that you still link to OpenGL32.lib if you're
>   building a 64-bit executable. The "32" part is meaningless)....

After we include OpenGL32.lib in the linker settings, we need to

```
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <GL\glext.h>
```

, so that we had all the extended function definitions.

So after that we create a window with `CreateWindowEx`, 
set a proper pixel format to the window's HDC. Without proper setting of pixel format the next command will give error.
After that we `wglCreateContext()`, check that it's not returning a NULL
next, `wglMakeCurrent()` - enter the current GL context and load all the bunch of needed functions manually; one by one.

```
PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC glAttachShader;
PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC glCompileShader;
PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram;

glCompileShader=(PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
glAttachShader=(PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glAttachShader");
glCreateProgram=(PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
```